# Help in bypassing a defective knob in an airconditioning unit

Tags: switches, analog, appliances

I would like to ask for help fixing my airconditioning unit.
Please see image for a clearer picture of my problem.

So I have a defective knob for switching on/off my airconditioning unit.
Since its very old and finding a spare part is hard, i would like to bypass this defective knob.

===========UPDATE # 1==========


<strike>Based on my research, i can connect wire 1 and 3 so that it is always ON. (Please see image)

I don't know what to do with wire 2. (It seems to be connected to the thermostat)


Questions:

1. is connecting wire 1 and 3 correct to make it always ON?

2. Anyone knows what to do with the wire 2. (the one connected to the thermostat)</strike>


Please see image for list of wires
Wire 1 connects to the capacitor.
Wire 2 connects to the thermostat, air swing switch and fan selector switch
Wire 3 connects to the power cord.

**I think that connecting wire 1, 2 and 3 will bypass the defective knob and make the airconditioning unit ALWAYS ON.**

Questions:
Does anyone think this is correct or incorrect?
Any theories on how to bypass to make it always ON?
Will anyone think there will be a big problem if I try to connect all 3 wires just for testing purposes?

Thank you. 
Any help is appreciated.

[image: control panel (Front and back)]

Comment: Can you share your research why you think it is wire 1 and 3 that need shorting?

Comment: Wire 3 is the one that is connected to the power source (outlet) and 
wire 1 goes inside the airconditioning unit.
The research is based on the youtube video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y07Axtya124

Comment: With the little information I have here, I would have guessed that 2 and 3 need connecting together.  It would make sense that the unit would then be controlled by the thermostat.  Wire 1 will be the permanent supply for the timer.  But that is just a guess with so little to go on.

Comment: Thanks HandyHowie, will do some testing and further digging on the AC unit..

Comment: I made some updates on the wires and where it connects to. Hope it is more clearer. Thank you.

Comment: Where do those 2 wires from the motor on the switch go to?

Comment: Sorry but which 2 wires?
Wire 1 connects to the capacitor. (not seen in the picture).
Wire 2 connects to the thermostat, air swing switch and fan selector switch.
Wire 3 connects to the power cord.
Thanks.

Comment: The 2 soldered wires.  One looks like it goes through that sleeved resistor? To pin 1 the other looks like it may connect to pin 2.

Comment: It (Wire 2) just connects to the thermostat then the air swing switch then fan selector switch and ends there. It basically just connects all the switches/controls in the control panel and thats it..

Answer (score 1):

The defective part is a 12-hour time switch to set how long the AC is to run before it switches off automatically.

When the knob is at 'OFF' position the AC will remain off.
When it is at 'ON' position the AC will run till the knob is turned to 'OFF' position.

The intermediate positions are for setting the time.

The timer could be run by a motor.

The wires would be 'Line', 'Neutral' & 'Output'.

For bypassing the timer 'Line' & 'Output' are to be shorted.

The 'Line' & 'Output' may be identified using a multimeter. There should be no continuity between 'Line' & 'Output' when the knob is in the 'Off' position. The continuity should be there in all other positions of the knob.

Comment: The switch is broken, therefore your tests won’t indicate anything.

Comment: Yes, i agree that using multimeter wont help since knob is broken... Since this is a very old unit, finding a spare part is quite hard.